# Passing an array of data to a private function in CodeIgniter/PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, private-functions

So I thought this should be easy, but, I'm struggling here...

Here's my code:

```
function xy() {
  $array['var1'] = x;
  $array['var2'] = y;
  echo $this->_z;
}

function _z($array) {
  $xy = $x.$y;
  return $xy;
}
```

So, why doesn't that seemingly simple code work? I know with views you can pass arrays and the variables are accessible in the views with just their array title, but, why doesn't it work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `function _z` is not a view. Call it with `$this->_z($array);`. Also views are processed by CodeIgniter and variables passed into them. This doesn't work the same way for non-views. PHP won't do that automatically for you.

To load a view make a view file in `/system/application/views/` and call it with `$this->load->view('my_view_name', $array);`

I would rewrite your functions as follows:

```
function xy()
{
    $x = "some value";
    $y = "some other value";

    echo $this->_z($x, $y);
}

function _z($a, $b)
{
    return $a.$b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, but, I don't want to load a view. I want to pass data to a private function for it to deal with, format accordingly, then return to be echoed from my public function.

Comment: Just re-read your answer... and comprehended it a bit more :D thanks, I'll see where I can go with it.

Comment: @Jack: You can't create an array of key values and pass it to a function and have them available by name (as it works in the views). I'll write some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic the CI views behavior you want with the PHP native function **extract()** (That is how CI does it)

```
function xy() {
    $some_array = array(
        'foo' => 'Hello',
        'bar' => 'world'
    );
    echo $this->_z($some_array);
}

function _z($array) {
    extract ($array);
    $xy = "$foo $bar";
    return $xy;
}


xy();
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 0):

One of the best explanation about accessing array from a function to a private function. thanks the code helped me

```
function _normal()
```

{
$arrayVariable = "value you want to pass";

```
echo $this->_toPrivateFuction($arrayVariable);
```

}

function _toPrivateFuction($arrayVariable)
{

// or print to check if you have the desired result

```
print_r(arrayVariable);
```

// if yes then you are ready to go!

```
return $arrayVariable;
```

}